# Funcion "fail" de Ajax no lee Json de respuesta

Tags: ajax, json, django

Según si el **form** es válido o no deberían aparecer "**success**" o "**some errors**" en un **div** con **id="results"**.

El problema surge cuando el **form** no es válido.

En la función "**fail**" de Ajax solo se ejecuta el "**alert**" y no lee el Json de respuesta enviado desde **Django**.

En la función "**done**" todo funciona correctamente.

Estoy usando "**Firebug**" para ver si desde la view se envia correctamente la información y  aparentemente no hay problemas.

Dejo los códigos usados. Gracias de antemano.

> Ajax.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#form').submit( function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    type : 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url:'/wind/buildings',
})
 .done(function(data) {
    $("#result").html(data.result);
    $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#result").offset().top},
    'slow');
    alert('success');
})
.fail(function(data) {
    $("#result").html(data.result);
    alert('error');
});
});
})
```

> Django View

```
def buildings(request):
    if request.POST and request.is_ajax():
        s_form = BuildingForm(request.POST)
        if s_form.is_valid():
            return JsonResponse({'result': 'success'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'result': 'some errors'}, status=400)
    else:
        s_form = BuildingForm()
        return render(request, 'wind/buildings.html', {'s_form': s_form})
```

Comment: Desde la consola del inspector de tu navegador ¿ya comprobaste que efecitvamente exista `data.result`?

Comment: Me aparece esta respuesta. {"result": "some errors"}   [Imagen](http://i.imgur.com/iXEUIqv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el caso de un **fail** se recibe xhr no data directamente. Por lo tanto tienes que buscar ahi el JSON con los errores.

```
.fail(function(xhr) {
   data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
   $("#result").html(data.result);
   alert('error');
}
```

Comment: Perfecto! Lo unico que tuve que cambiar para que funcione fue reemplazar el argumento **response** por **xhr**.

Comment: Ah perdon mezcle eso. Ya lo arreglo para futuras referencias.